# How to access to another column's value from a column in v7 (React-Table)

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7

I see in previous versions that you can access it using :

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name",
    Cell: (e) => {
      return e.original.name;
    }
  }
];
```

But in v7 it doesn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In v7 the `Cell` gets called with a `props` object.  One of the props is the `row` which has the `original` property that you are looking for.

```
{
  Header: 'Name',
  Cell: (props) => {
    return (
      <>{props.row.original.lastName}, {props.row.original.firstName}</>
    );
  }
},
```

You can destructure the `row` from the props.

```
{
  Header: 'Name',
  accessor: 'firstName',
  Cell: ({row, value}) => (
    <span onClick={() => alert(row.original.lastName)}>{value}</span>
  )
},
```

Comment: is there any way to get the raw value of the cell. like if use an input tag as an value.how can i get that?

Comment: That’s the variable value in the second example.